# Unexpected token 'interpolation' nodejs

Tags: node.js, pug

I am getting this error I am trying to get the href to be /sendnotify/room.roomNumber.

```
Error: /root/13h31762/views/classmanager.jade:14
    12|                                 -var roomurl = "/sendnotify/"+ room.roomNumber;
    13|                                 li your Classes --->
  > 14|                                 a(href=roomurl, class='roomlink')#{room.roomName}
    15|                                 
    16| 

Unexpected token `interpolation` expected `text`, `code`, `:`, `newline` or `eos`
```

I have no clue why.  My jade view is included below

```
extends layout

block content
    div.container
        div.row
            div.col-sm-6.col-md-4.col-md-offset-4
            #user
                    h1.text-center.login-title Welcome #{user.firstName}. Check your details below:
                        div.signup-wall
                            ul.user-details
                            each room in user.room
                                -var roomurl = "/sendnotify/"+ room.roomNumber;
                                li your Classes --->
                                a(href=roomurl, class='roomlink')#{room.roomName}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a space before your variable for roomname:

```
a(href=roomurl, class='roomlink') #{room.roomName}
```

Or since you only have the variable in the a-tag you can use:

```
a(href=roomurl, class='roomlink')= room.roomName
```